# Telas em Tkinter-Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Estou com dificuldade em voltar para uma tela sem que crie outra...
Não consegui fazer com que ela voltasse a mesma tela criada.
Será que eu posso usar o `.destroy()`?
Segue abaixo o código:

```
from tkinter import *

def janela_principal():
   janela1 = Tk()
   janela1.geometry("300x300+200+200")
   janela1 ["bg"] = "green"

bt1 = Button(janela1, text="abrir a segunda janela",command = janela_secundaria)
bt1.place(x = 50, y =100)

def janela_secundaria():
   janela2 = Tk()
   janela2.geometry("300x300+200+200")
   janela2["bg"] = "green"

bt1 = Button(janela2, text = "Voltar", command = janela_principal)
bt1.place(x = 50, y = 100)

janela_principal()
```

Comment: Quando eu mexi com `TkInter`, eu sempre trabalhei na mesma janela. Mexia no conteúdo dela, mas não a destruía jamais

Answer (score 0):

Sempre que você instancia `janela = Tk()` você abre uma nova janela.

`bt1 = Button(janela2, text = "Voltar", command = janela2.destroy)` pode resolver o seu problema sim.

Talvez usar Toplevel(master) em lugar de Tk() seja melhor pra você. Eu uso em conjunto com transient, o que me permite abrir uma nova janela na frente da anterior e quando fechar a anterior, a nova fecha automaticamente.

```
from tkinter import *

def janela_principal():
   janela1 = Tk()
   janela1.geometry("300x300+200+200")
   janela1 ["bg"] = "green"

   bt1 = Button(janela1, text="abrir a segunda janela",command = lambda e:
   janela_secundaria(janela1)) ## der erro, apague o 'e' no lambda e:
   bt1.place(x = 50, y =100)

def janela_secundaria(master):
   janela2 = Toplevel(master)
   janela2.transient(master)
   janela2.geometry("300x300+200+200")
   janela2["bg"] = "green"

   bt1 = Button(janela2, text = "Voltar", command = janela2.destroy)
   bt1.place(x = 50, y = 100)

janela_principal()
```